# how to find the number of open files per process

Tags: rhel, kernel, ps, file-descriptors, lsof

we have kafka service ( as `systemctl` service )

and we configured in that service number of open files

example:

```
[Service]
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
LimitNOFILE=1500000
Type=forking
User=root
Group=kafka
```

now when service is up , we want to understand the consuming of number of files by kafka services

from googled , I understand from - https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-get-list-of-open-files/

that we can use the command `fstat` in order to capture the number of open files

as

```
fstat -p {PID}
```

since we are using production RHEL 7.6 secured server , then its not clear if `fstat` can be installed on our server

therefore we want to learn about other ideas?

appreciate to get other approach

other approach as suggest is by - `ls  "/proc/$pid/fd"`

but here is real example from my machine

```
ls /proc/176909/fd  |more
0
1
10
100
1000
10000
10001
10002
10003
10004
10005
10006
10007
10008
10009
1001
10010
10011
10012
.
.
.
```

so we get a long list of numbers , so how to find the count of open files ?

Comment: The link you gave mentions `fstat` for FreeBSD and `ls  "/proc/$pid/fd"` for Linux. RHEL is a Linux distribution, not FreeBSD.

Comment: ls /proc/176909/fd
 gives a lot of numbers , how to capture the current number ?

Comment: Run `ls -l`. You will see that those are symlinks to various files, devices, sockets, etc. You could do  `ls -1 /proc/176909/fd | wc -l`. `ls -1 /proc/176909/fd` puts every listed item out on a separate line in one column. `wc -l` counts the number of lines. So this would give you the total number of items in that directory. I think you should just keep reading the link you posted as it says all of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LimitNOFILE` directive in `systemd` (see `man systemd.exec`) corresponds to the `RLIMIT_NOFILE` resource limit as set with `setrlimit()` (see `man setrlimit`). Can be set in some shells with `ulimit -n` or `limit descriptors`.

> This  specifies  a value one greater than the maximum file descriptor number that can be opened by this process.  Attempts (open(2), pipe(2), dup(2), etc.)  to exceed this limit yield the error EMFILE.  (Historically, this limit was named RLIMIT_OFILE on BSD.)

So it's not strictly speaking the limit of number of open file descriptors (let alone open files) in that a process with that limit could have more open files if it had fds above the limit prior to that limit being set (or inherited upon creation (`clone()` / `fork()`)) and could not get a fd above the limit even if it had very few opened fds.

On Linux, `/proc/<pid>/fd` is a special directory that contains one magic symlink file for each fd that the process has opened.

You can get their number by counting them:

```
() {print $#} /proc/$pid/fd/*(NoN)
```

in `zsh` for instance (or `ls "/proc/$pid/fd" | wc -l` as already shown by Romeo).

You can get the highest pid value by sorting them numerically in reverse and get the first.

```
() {print $1} /proc/$pid/fd/*(NnOn:t)
```

Or with GNU `ls`: `ls -rv "/proc/$pid/fd" | head -n1`

To get a report of number of open fds for all processes, you could do something like:

```
(for p (/proc/<->) () {print -r $# $p:t $(<$p/comm) $p/exe(:P)} $p/fd/*(NoN)) | sort -n
```

More portably, you could resort to `lsof`:

```
lsof -ad0-2147483647 -Ff -p "$pid" | grep -c '^f'
```

For the number of open file descriptors and:

```
lsof -ad0-2147483647 -Ff -p "$pid" | sed -n '$s/^f//p'
```

For the highest.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in comments you can use `wc` command:

```
ls  "/proc/$pid/fd"|wc -l
```

`-l` count the number of lines (result of `ls` command)